# Bulk update in grails

Tags: grails, batch-updates, bulkupdate

I'm using grails 2.2.2 and mysql database.There are 800 records in my table(which will increase over time).I have to update a particular column value to a new value based on some calculations. Please suggest a way which does not impact the performance.

Answer (score 3):

In such cases I'm usually flushing the session each 1000 or so objects:

```
SomeDomain.list().eachWithIndex{ obj, ix ->
  obj.doSomeCalc()
  obj.save flush:0 == ix % 1000
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using a the `Model.withTransaction()` method that allows for batch updates when using `Model.save()` on multiple instances, using the following link: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/batch-processing-in-grails/

For example:

```
List batch = []
(0..1000).each {
    Model model = new Model(...)
    batch.add(model)
    Model.withTransaction {
        for (Model m in batch) {
            m.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Further, to prevent `OutOfMemoryExceptions`, you can include the `SessionFactory` object in your method, get the current session object, and clear it with `session.clear()` at regular intervals.

Before this update, it was taking 53 secs to update rows with `save()`, now it's taking 794ms to update 800 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This might help : http://geekcredential.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/bulk-insert-with-grails/

You can bypass the grails GORM and go down to HQL level to insert or update objects, this will reduce the chances of you getting an outofmemory exception as there will be no validation objects, errors and other to consume the memory. Another approach is to flush session, clear validation errors and objects after each insert or update.